# RapidSQL (Embacadero) error db2abind.dll is missing

Tags: db2, rapidsql

I just installed rapidSQL 8.0.1 and tried connecting to a valid database.  I'm fairly certain I have the right connection data (it was imported from another developer), but I'm getting the following error:

db2abind.dll Cannot be loaded!  That will severely impact use of this application.  Please restore the missing library.

I have created a ticket with Embarcadero, but I was wondering if anyone else has had this problem and have a solution.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So this was being caused by the fact that I didn't have a DB2 client installed on my machine.  I chose a light db2 client from among the many(!) available at IBM, and it got me past this issue.

http://www.db2dean.com/Previous/DB2Client.html

The above link was a good resource on understanding what was going on with IBM clients and DB2 connectivity.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the publib](http://publib.boulder.ibm.com/infocenter/db2luw/v9/index.jsp?topic=/com.ibm.db2.udb.admin.doc/doc/r0004670.htm), `db2abind.dll`'s functionality has been moved into `db2app.dll` since version 9 for Linux, Unix, Windows.  It also mentions that at that time, stub DLLs were provided for convenience sake, but would be removed in a future version.

Since LUW is now on version 9.7, perhaps this removal has taken place.

> ***Application libraries have changed***
>
> **Operating systems affected**
>
> All supported operating systems are affected.
>
> **Change**
>
> The following changes have been made:
>
> db2app.dll was extended. It includes its original information, plus
>   the information from the db2util.dll, db2abind.dll, and db2cli.dll
>   libraries. db2api.dll was extended. It includes its original
>   information, plus the information from the db2cli.dll library.
>
> **Explanation**
>
> The library information is being consolidated.
>
> **Resolution**
>
> Stubs for the db2util.dll, db2abind.dll, and db2cli.dll
>   libraries are still available for backwards compatibility. These stubs
>   will be removed in a future version or release of the product. You
>   should rebuild your application using the changed libraries.

Comment: Not exactly what I was looking for, but good information nonetheless.